# How to check a JCSMPSession state?

Tags: solace

I wonder how to get the state of a JCSMPSession - whether the session is still up or already lost (stale session).  This would be useful if I implement my own JCSMPSession pool so that I can perform housekeeping on stale JCSMPSession, either removing the session or re-creating the session. If there is no way to get the state of a JCSMPSession, one way I could think of is to just publish a message to a dummy topic (topic with no known subscribers) and catch specifically for the unchecked StaleSessionException. Or, there is a more elegant/efficient way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be a need to check a stale JCSMPSession.

The API does [keep-alive checks](https://docs.solace.com/Solace-PubSub-Messaging-APIs/Developer-Guide/Setting-Client-Keepalive.htm), and has a [reconnection logic](https://docs.solace.com/Solace-PubSub-Messaging-APIs/Developer-Guide/Configuring-Connection-T.htm#Sample) if the session goes down.

If you want to track the session state at the application, see https://docs.solace.com/Solace-PubSub-Messaging-APIs/Developer-Guide/Handling-Session-Events.htm.

That is done via [`SessionEventHandler`](https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/java/com/solacesystems/jcsmp/SessionEventHandler.html), which is a callback when a particular [`SessionEvent`](https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/java/com/solacesystems/jcsmp/SessionEvent.html) occurred. It is registered when the session is [created](https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/java/com/solacesystems/jcsmp/JCSMPFactory.html#createSession(com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPProperties,%20com.solacesystems.jcsmp.Context,%20com.solacesystems.jcsmp.SessionEventHandler)), e.g.

```
JCSMPSession session = JCSMPFactory.onlyInstance().createSession(properties, null, evtHdlr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although we can set the various properties in JCSMPChannelProperties for reconnect retry logic control, in a prolonged Solace downtime, it is necessary for our application to be able to reconnect when Solace is up after exhausting the retry window.  This is especially important when we are running our application as a daemon/service which internally uses JCSMP to communicate with Solace. The last thing we want is to restart our application to reconnect to Solace after prolonged downtime.  This is also important when we are implementing own connection pool to Solace using JCSMP.

Actually, com.solacesystems.jcsmp.SessionEvent.DOWN_ERROR is all I need.

We have a class implementing com.solacesystems.jcsmp.SessionEventHandler which checks for com.solacesystems.jcsmp.SessionEvent.DOWN_ERROR.  Upon detecting this, we retry the following:

```
JCSMPSession session = JCSMPFactory.onlyInstance().createSession(properties, null, evtHdlr);
```

We will continue monitoring for SessionEvent.DOWN_ERROR and retry the above.  So, it is possible to detect for stale session and recover gracefully at application level.

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution! Make sure to accept the answer that helped you to it.